# How to load json into my angular.js ng-model?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, model

I have what I think is probably a very obvious question, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I am just trying to load some JSON data from my server into the client. Right now, I am using JQuery to load it with an AJAX call (code below).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var global = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url: "/json",
    success: function(reports){
        global = reports;
        return global;
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is located in the html file. It works so far, but the issue is that I want to use AngularJS. Now, while Angular CAN use the variables, i cannot load the whole thing into a variable so I can use a for each loop. This seems to be related to the "$Scope", which is usually located in the .js file.

The problem is that I cannot load code from other pages into a .js file. Every example of Angular only shows stuff like this:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [
    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
    {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];
```

So, this is useful, if I 
A) Want to type all of this by hand, AND 
B) If I know in advance what all my data is...

I don't know in advance (the data is dynamic) and I don't want to type it.

So, when I tried to change the AJAX call to Angular using $Resource, it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I can't figure it out, but it is a relatively simple GET request for JSON data.

**tl:dr I can't get AJAX calls to work in order to load external data into an angular model.**

Comment: Can we see your attempt at using $Resource? It should work, so perhaps it's easiest if we help you debug that...

Answer (score 189, accepted):

As Kris mentions, you can use the `$resource` service to interact with the server, but I get the impression you are beginning your journey with Angular - I was there last week - so I recommend to start experimenting directly with the `$http` service. In this case you can call its `get` method.

If you have the following JSON

```
[{ "text":"learn angular", "done":true },
 { "text":"build an angular app", "done":false},
 { "text":"something", "done":false },
 { "text":"another todo", "done":true }]
```

You can load it like this

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('todos.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.todos = res.data;                
        });
});
```

The `get` method returns a *promise* object which
first argument is a *success* callback and the second an *error*
callback.

When you add `$http` as a parameter of a function Angular does it magic
and injects the `$http` resource into your controller.

I've put some examples here

- http://plnkr.co/edit/Wuc6M7?p=preview
- https://gist.github.com/3938567

Comment: thanks so much, I did end up using the $http service instead...albeit a slightly different way...
`code`
$http.get('/json').success(
            function(response){
                $scope.reports = response;
                getData();
`code`

what is interesting to me, is the promise object...I really want to learn more about that. I love the idea of it.

The other problem I have been having is basically running a loop on the ajax request so i can constantly "automagically" refresh the page. $timeout has not been working for me.

Comment: I believe it should be $scope.todos = res;  instead of res.data.

Comment: The response object has four properties: `config`, `data`, `headers` and `status`. The values in the `data` property are what you want.

Comment: worth having a $scope.todos = []; before the http request, so you at least have a default empty structure so as not to throw errors in your template.

Comment: This example works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: re: `$scope.todos = res;` or `$scope.todos = res.data;` -- the difference is whether you are in a `.then(response)` or in a `.success(result)`  The `.success` is given `response.data` while the `.then` is given the entire `response`.

Answer (score 28):

Here's a simple example of how to load JSON data into an Angular model.

I have a JSON 'GET' web service which returns a list of Customer details, from an online copy of Microsoft's Northwind *SQL Server* database.

http://www.iNorthwind.com/Service1.svc/getAllCustomers

It returns some JSON data which looks like this:

```
{ 
    "GetAllCustomersResult" : 
        [
            {
              "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
              "CustomerID": "ALFKI"
            },
            {
              "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
              "CustomerID": "ANATR"
            },
            {
              "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
              "CustomerID": "ANTON"
            }
        ]
    }
```

..and I want to populate a drop down list with this data, to look like this...

[image: Angular screenshot]

I want the text of each item to come from the "CompanyName" field, and the ID to come from the "CustomerID" fields.

How would I do it ?

My Angular controller would look like this:

```
function MikesAngularController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.listOfCustomers = null;

    $http.get('http://www.iNorthwind.com/Service1.svc/getAllCustomers')
         .success(function (data) {
             $scope.listOfCustomers = data.GetAllCustomersResult;
         })
         .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             //  Do some error handling here
         });
}
```

... which fills a "listOfCustomers" variable with this set of JSON data.

Then, in my HTML page, I'd use this:

```
<div ng-controller='MikesAngularController'>
    <span>Please select a customer:</span>
    <select ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-options="customer.CustomerID as customer.CompanyName for customer in listOfCustomers" style="width:350px;"></select>
</div>
```

And that's it.  We can now see a list of our JSON data on a web page, ready to be used.

The key to this is in the "ng-options" tag:

```
customer.CustomerID as customer.CompanyName for customer in listOfCustomers
```

It's a strange syntax to get your head around !

When the user selects an item in this list, the "$scope.selectedCustomer" variable will be set to the ID (the CustomerID field) of that Customer record.

The full script for this example can be found here:

[JSON data with Angular](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page8.5.htm)

Mike

Comment: Does this actually work? Your JSON is invalid (the keys are not in quotation marks). Don't you get errors?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I took the screenshot above from Google Chrome with the excellent JSONView addin installed (so you can view the JSON in a nicely formatted way).   But yes, the JSON from my web service is valid.  If you click on the link in my article, you can view a live version of this code.

Comment: Does it work? i think it should be  data.GetAllCustomersResult

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right.  I had changed the web service to include wrapping the JSON results in "GetAllCustomersResult", so yes, this is needed.  I've updated the code sample.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code, found somewhere in the internet don't remember the source though.

```
    var allText;
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
    return JSON.parse(allText);
```