# Create html from json fetched with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, symfony

**What I want to do:**

I have an application based on symfony2 (php). A simple action returns data as json like this

```
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    );

    return new Response($data, 200, $headers);
```

This action is called from javascript like this

```
function loadData(action){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

So this seems very basic so far. From the console I can see the correct data returned. This data should be  placed somewhere on the project website.

**Question:**

Is there any straight forward way to create html from json within javascript? Actually I want seperate templates (twig) from the logic of the project. So would it be correct to generate the html e.g. in the success callback in the loadData method?

I could bypass this problem by returning html instead of json. But I think about building some kind of rest api for my project which I think required json for transport.

Any suggestions or ideas? Please share your ways of handling this.

Comment: Of course but where is your json. i mean a sample of your json response

Comment: Just a note but for a JSON response you can use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse->create()` without the need to send your own headers or status stuff.

Comment: "I could bypass this problem by returning html instead of json. But I think about building some kind of rest api for my project which I think required json for transport." could you explain more about this?

Comment: You could do like Facebook does and return a pre generated HTML using `$view = $this->renderView('Blah:Blah:some_content.html.twig, $vars)` then `return new JsonResponse(array('view' => $view))` and finally using jQuery to fill the space needed using `return (data) {$('#blah').html(data.view);}` but then it's not overly portable.

Comment: @Jai json response is a serialized set of objects

Comment: @ianace I mean it juts like Qoop explains it in his comment, just without the json part

Comment: @Qoop sounds like a good way to do this

Comment: @artworkadシ i mean what's preventing you from doing something like this.. put all html inside an array and json encode that array? for example $array_to_be_json = array('header'=> /*html placed inside a php variable here*/  ,'footer'=> /*another html placed inside php variable*/); echo json_encode($array_to_be_json)  ... then let javascript parse that object append accordingly to what the index is.. 
am i making sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [angular js](http://angularjs.org/). It have one good thing for **symfony**:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
    };
);
```

It changes `{{` with `[[` and let you use template in **TWIG**.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13031318/739897) will help with **json query** in angular js.

Comment: Great thing. Gonna give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Get the data and send it back to the server ? I think its not correct.

Try to look at [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) ( _.template() ) for templating on client side with received json object.

And try to use TWIG like this:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g
};

var template = _.template("Hello [[ name ]]!");
template({name : "Mustache"});
=> "Hello Mustache!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

You can basically pass the JSON to a Handlebars template:

**The template:**

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div class="body">
            {{body}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**The JS:**

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html(),
    template = Handlebars.compile(source),
    context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"},
    html    = template(context);
```

**The result:**

```
<div class="entry">
    <h1>My New Post</h1>
    <div class="body">
        This is my first post!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In `twig` used same syntax `{{` so there will be problem with using it in templates. Is there any method to change `{{` with `[[` for example?

Comment: In this case you will not be able to use for example system vars in twig.

Comment: You can end the verbatim tag at any time.