# AngularJS: How to load JSON data onto a scope variable

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm creating a personal website where I can keep updating content without having to manipulate the `HTML`. I'm trying to achieve this by simply loading and updating a `JSON` file. But right now, I'm having trouble loading `JSON` data onto a `scope` variable.

*HTML*

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainController">
            <div id="content">
                <div ng-repeat="content in contents">
                    <h2>{{content.heading}}</h2>
                    <p>{{content.description}}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*maincontroller.js*

```
var myapp = angular.module('mainApp', []);
myapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http){

    $scope.contents = null;
    $http.get('mainContent.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.contents=data;
        })
        .error(function(data,status,error,config){
            $scope.contents = [{heading:"Error",description:"Could not load json   data"}];
        });

    //$scope.contents = [{heading:"Content heading", description:"The actual content"}];
    //Just a placeholder. All web content will be in this format
});
```

This is what the `JSON` file looks like

```
[
    {"heading":"MyHeading","description":"myDescription"},
]
```

I actually tried following the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020821/how-to-load-json-into-my-angular-js-ng-model), but it's not loading the `JSON` file stored in the same folder. The output I get is from the error handling function which is saying `Error: Cannot load JSON data` as mentioned.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I put the same code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fIGAt3RAFS4xe527UAIU?p=preview) and it works fine. It's just not working on my local machine.

Comment: try removing the trailing comma. make sure the JSON validates @ jsonlint.com

Comment: For security purposes, most browsers will prevent AJAX requests to the filesystem, which could cause this error... are you running your code on a local server, or just opening your HTML file directly in your browser?  You'll need to setup a simple server if you haven't already.

Answer (score 6):

Modified Your Method Use this and Check output.

```
var myapp=angular.module('mainApp',[]);
myapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.content = null;
    $http.get('urlpath'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.contents=data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {          
    });
});
```

or Another Good Practice I see

Use  Factory Service Method:-

```
angular.module('mainApp').factory('Myservice', function($http){
    return {
        getdata: function(){
              return $http.get('url'); // You Have to give Correct Url either Local path or api etc 
           
        }
    };
});
```

Inject above service to Controller

Controller :-

```
angular.module('mainApp',[]).controller('mainController',function($scope,Myservice){
        $scope.content = null;
         Myservice.getdata().success(function (data){
           alert('Success');
           $scope.content=data[0]; // as per  emilySmitley Answer which is Working Good
         });
      });
```

Let Me Know if You have any Questions. Good Luck

Answer (score 5):

Your json file has an array with the first and only element in the array being a json object. When `.success()` fires, and data is passed into the lambda function, data is an array, not just json. All you have to do is access the zeroth element of the array.

So this:

```
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.contents = data;
})
```

Should be this:

```
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.contents = data[0];
})
```

---

Also, you should check `data[0]` to make sure that it's json, and if it doesn't validate, you should probably call `parseJSON(data[0])` on it.

Comment: Sorry, that's not working. I'm sure my problem is exactly the same as in this tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @emilySmitley Dude the Above Concept You Explained Damn Good .. I have been Wondering  Why It is Not Saving data. "Thanks A LOT You ". "Thanks A LOT You " :-)

Comment: Dude Do you have any idea about time Subtractions with Momentjs ?

Comment: You should ask that as a stack overflow question @PRASAD

Answer (score 2):

```
var myapp=angular.module('mainApp',[]);
myapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.content = null;
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'mainContent.json'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.contents=data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {          
    });
});
```

Published in Web Server and added Mime type for .json. It worked.

Comment: When You Injected $http service  Use '$http.get' which is Straight and Easy . I Answered  Take a Look and Let me Know your Questions

Answer (score 0):

Change your mainController.js and JSON files as follows. Here i'm using wamp server as my local server.

```
var myapp = angular.module('mainApp', []);
myapp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/stackoverflow/angular/test1/database.json').success (function(data) {
    $scope.contents = data.records;
  })
});
```

JSON File:

```
{
 "records":
 [
    {"heading":"MyHeading","description":"myDescription"}
 ]
}
```

Comment: nice, but how you call this on the html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have still been able out the solution or not.
If not, do try this.
When using localhost server, the server is unable to locate the json files.
To solve this problem, just rename your file to mainContent.txt, apart from that, your code is perfect.
But do remember that this is only for development phase, once you plan to deploy the site live, change back to .json file.

updated $http request :-

```
$scope.contents = null;
$http.get('mainContent.json')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.contents=data;
    })
    .error(function(data,status,error,config){
        $scope.contents = [{heading:"Error",description:"Could not load json   data"}];
    });
```