# Dinamically switch between languages from JSON files using $translateProvider on Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I have a folder with 6 different JSON files.

```
en.json
es.json
fr.json
it.json
ja.json
zh.json
```

An example of the content that is inside of each file is like the following (this case is for en.json):

```
{
    "SomeText": "Test in English"
}
```

I am currently using this on my config file.

```
$translateProvider.translations
(
    'en',
    {
        SomeText: 'Test in English'
    }
)
.translations
(
    'zh',
    {
        SomeText: 'Test in Chinese'
    }
)
.translations
(
    'it',
    {
        SomeText: 'Test in Italian'
    }
)
.translations
(
    'fr',
    {
        SomeText: 'Test in French'
    }
)
.translations
(
    'ja',
    {
        SomeText: 'Test in Japanese'
    }
)
.translations
(
    'es',
    {
        SomeText: 'Test in Spanish'
    }
);
```

This last example works perfectly fine for what I want to accomplish, which is doing an initial load of english, and then if I switch languages, it will automatically refresh it.

```
var example = 'ja';
$translate.use(example);
```

However, now I want to use JSON files for a better structure, but I don't think I can use that same syntax.

How can I add all 6 files to the config and have them switched from any function like in the example above?

Comment: Could you give an example of the contents in the JSON-files? You want to load all files and add the contents to $translationProvider.translations?

Comment: I updated the post, showing an example of how the files look like

Comment: Did you try just fetching the files with $http? $http.get("/location/en.json").then(function(data){ // Add contents }, function(error){ alert(error); });

Comment: What backend are you using btw?

Comment: Check out this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020821/how-to-load-json-into-my-angular-js-ng-model (Load .json with $http in AngularJS).

Answer (score 0):

Treat it like an array (example in javascript):

```
var translations = 
{ 
    "en" : { "SomeText" : "Test in English" },
    "zh" : { "SomeText" : "Test in Chinese" },
    "it" : { "SomeText" : "Test in Italian" },
    "fr" : { "SomeText" : "Test in French" },
    "ja" : { "SomeText" : "Test in Japanese" },
    "es" : { "SomeText" : "Test in Spanish" }
});
```

then it would be something like:

```
var language = "en";
var translations[language].SomeText;
```

This would give "Test in English"

I'm not 100% sure of the structure of the app but I think it gives you the basic concept.

javascript example https://jsfiddle.net/uw0pg8jm/

This way it would be easy to change between languages, say you have two phrases, this is an example in jQuery and javascript. Using Angualar you would bind the events and values differently. https://jsfiddle.net/zu6h7nh7/1/