# Pass data from PHP to AngularJS efficiently

Tags: php, angularjs, phalcon

Right now, we're in the process of moving our frontend to AngularJS. I'm fetching all users with a model `Users`. Right after doing that, I'm passing the data to AngularJS. This is the code:

```
$users = Users::find();

$users_array = array();

foreach ($users as $user) {

    if ($user->user) {
        $birthDate = explode("-", $user->user->getBirthdate());

        if (count($birthDate) > 2) {
            $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md")
                    ? ((date("Y") - $birthDate[2]) - 1)
                    : (date("Y") - $birthDate[2]));
         } else {
             $age = "";

         }

         $array = array('id' => $user->user->getId(), 'firstname' => $user->user->getFirstname(), 'lastname' => $user->user->getLastname(), 'birthDate' => $age, 'gender' => $user->user->getGenderNeat());
         array_push($users_array, $array);
    }
}

return $users_array;
```

This isn't very efficient, because I'm looping over all users in the database. I do need to do something similar to this, because I can't query the models in AngularJS. Are there any better options? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Have you considered paginating `Users`?

Comment: `echo json_encode($users_array);` then pass it to Angular using this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020821/how-to-load-json-into-my-angular-js-ng-model