# how can I read appsettings.json from angular?

Tags: .net, angularjs

I am trying to read from appsettings.json on angular and set the url depending on the settings on appsettings.json.

On my appsettings.json I have defined the url for the test and dev environments.

I want on angular to set the urls depending on that file.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load json into my angular.js ng-model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020821/how-to-load-json-into-my-angular-js-ng-model)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$http.get('path/to/appsettings.json')` to get the data from your json file.

Comment: Seems like this would be a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: This approach also falls over when you are using routing